# Make XML HTTP request to Chrome Extension from vbscript

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, google-chrome-extension, vbscript, xmlhttprequest

Here is the script, I need it to return the DOM of the popup html of my chrome extension:

```
URL="chrome-extension://jclgkomglckpklainiafinmjchonokdl/popup.html"
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set http = CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")

On Error Resume Next
http.open "GET", URL, False
http.send ""
If err.Number = 0 Then
    Wscript.Echo http.responseText
Else
    Wscript.Echo "error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
End If
set WshShell = Nothing
Set http = Nothing
```

It works for sites that have http:// before it, but won't work for the link above. Putting http:// before said link doesn't work either. Is there any way that this could work with the chrome-extension? If not, are there any other suggestions as to how this could be done?

PS the vbscript is part of a batch file so I can just double click to set the extension and its webpages up.

Comment: What do you mean by `the vbscript is part of a batch file`? As your question currently stands the relevance of your batch file tag is in doubt.

Comment: I dont think it is possible in the way you attend. `Microsoft.XmlHttp` can comunicate through `http` protocol , but `chrome-extension` is a chrome specific protocol.Eventually you can try trhough [chrome-driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chromedriver) and node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't communicate with a Chrome WebExtension from outside the browser. It is internal only.

You'd have to write your own WebExtension to interface with it or duplicate the functionality already implemented by another extension.

I advise you read up on the following:

- [Browser Extensions on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)
- [Chrome - What are Extensions?](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions)

The only other solution is to use VBScript or another tool that can remote-control the browser directly, such as [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/).